# bash script extract domain name for LDAP

Tags: bash

I am currently working on a script that asks the user entered a domain name. This domain name is used to fill the  hqbase variable for LDAP.
For example, if the user enter "example.com", i have to cut the domaine name with `example` on the side and "com" another side.

I found this example:

```
echo http://example.com/index.php | awk -F/ '{print $3}'
```

But how to split `example` from `com` (any ".").

Comment: How do you want to split `meta.stackoverflow.com` -- into 2 or 3 pieces?

Comment: I needed to extract the DNS zone from a URL (`bar.baz.example.com` from  `foo.bar.baz.example.com`). Cut is good for the subdomain, but for a URL with n parts, `ZONE=${FQDN#*.}` will set ZONE to everything after the first dot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `.` as your delimiter:

```
# Using cut
$ echo "domain.com" | cut -d. -f1
domain

$ echo "domain.com" | cut -d. -f2
com

# Using awk                                                                     
$ echo "domain.com" | awk -F. '{print $1}'
domain

$ echo "domain.com" | awk -F. '{print $2}'
com

# Save values                                                                   
$ first=$(echo "domain.com" | cut -d. -f1)
$ second=$(echo "domain.com" | cut -d. -f1)
```